# Update product quantity manually (external script) in prestashop

Tags: php, codeigniter, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

i am writing an external application in codeigniter, which will read barcode of products and update quantity in the **Prestashop** database. now i am not sure which table/tables i should update. there are _DB_PREFIX_product, _DB_PREFIX_product_attribute, _DB_PREFIX_stock_available tables in the db where, product id and quantity column is available.

and barcode column (ean13) is available in first 2 tables. 
please let me know which table or tables i should update to change the product qty properly

(prestashop version is 1.6)

Comment: i'm pretty sure there is a webservice for that available... in big shop systems it isn't a good idea to update data such as stock etc. over a database directly

Comment: thanks for your comment, yes there might be. but before updating there are some customization needed and i am not an expert in prestashop to modify its code. so i have to use an external application.

Answer (score 2):

Select `id_product` from `_DB_PREFIX_product` then update quantity in `_DB_PREFIX_stock_available`.

You can use prestashop classes, I have never worked with barcodes so dont know what is ean13 but the code must be.

```
<?php 
include('config/config.inc.php');
include('init.php'); 
$ean13 = "ean13";
$sql = "SELECT id_product FROM _DB_PREFIX_product WHERE ean13='$ean13'";
//replace _DB_PREFIX_ with your prefix or define _DB_PREFIX_ on top.
$product_id = Db::getInstance()->getValue($sql);
if (!empty($product_id)) {
$quantity = 100;
StockAvailable::setQuantity((int)$product_id, 0, $quantity);
}
?>
```

`StockAvailable::setQuantity((int)$product_id, 0, $quantity);` Here second parameter is of `id_product_attribute` why I pass `0` as `id_product_attribute` is in pestashop user can add stock for every attribute combination `e.g 300 quantity for blue color and Mediam size`.  So if you want to update the quantity of specific combination then you will have to pass the id of that combination as `id_product_attribute`. Passing `0` as `id_product_attribute` will update the overall quantity and stock of the product.

If you dont want to use prestashop classes and want to update db from external classes then the query will be `UPDATE _Db_PREFIX_stock_availble SET quantity='$quantity' WHERE id_product='$productID' AND id_product_attribute=0`

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your suggestion. i also guessed so, but the problem is there are multiple rows in `stock_available` table for each product id. unique is product_attribute id column. so i am not sure i should be searching barcode in `product` table or `product_attribute` table.

Comment: Multiple rows for 1 product in `PREFIX_stock_availble`  means there is seperate stock for every combination (size and colors), if you want to update the quantity of overall product then you will have to update the row where `id_product_attribute = 0`.